# kernel, basis and range for polynomial.

Tags: linear-transformations

$T: P_2$ $\to$ $P_3$ is a linear transformation defined by
$T(a+bx+cx^2)=3a+bx+2x^3$

a) Find $\ker(T)$ and give a basis for $\ker(T)$.
b) Find range$(T)$ and give a basis for range$(T)$.

Can anybody help me please?!
Thanks

Comment: Where do you need help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the kernel of a linear transformation, and a basis for its range](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756531/find-the-kernel-of-a-linear-transformation-and-a-basis-for-its-range)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how this is a linear transformation.  If you applied it to the zero polynomial ($a = b = c= 0$), you would get $2x^3$, a nonzero polynomial.